# React cache data in development

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, axios, create-react-app

App I'm working on retrieves a bunch of svg's from external source on start which in production get cached. In development though, each time I rebuild and the app restarts, all these resources are fetched again and again.

Is there some clean way of enforcing caching these resources in development?

Some additional info: it's a create-react-app project and the svg's I'm fetching as text with array of Axios get requests in Promise.all on root component mount